# useState's set state renders component immediatelly when called externally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following component with the `increase` method that updates two states in a row. By clicking the first button I see the expected behaviour in the console

```
rendered
a changed
b changed
```

that the component is rendered only once, after the two updates. However, by clicking the second button, I get the following output

```
rendered
a changed
rendered
b changed
```

It looks like that after every set state method of `useState` the render is triggered.

Can you explain to me why this is happening?

I am using React 17 in production mode.

```js
function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  const increase = useCallback(() => {
    setA(a + 1);
    setB(b + 1);
  }, [a, b]);

  console.log("rendered");

  useEffect(() => console.log("a changed"), [a]);
  useEffect(() => console.log("b changed"), [b]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.increase = increase;
  }, [increase]);


  return <>
    <button onClick={increase}>increase immediately</button>
    <button onClick={() => setTimeout(increase, 1000)}>increase in 1s</button>
  </>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **It's because Reactjs's update batching mechanism**

---

When updating state within an eventHandler like onChange, onClick,.etc.., React will batch all of `setState` into one:

```
<button onClick={increase}>increase immediately</button>
```

On the other hand, updating state outside an eventHander or wrapped inside a `promise` or a `setTimeout` in your case, they will not be batched:

```
<button onClick={() => setTimeout(increase, 1000)}>increase in 1s</button>
```

So your state will be updated synchronously, the first update causes a re-render and so on...

**But this behaviour will be changed in Reactjs 18 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950)**